# Should I use PropTypes and Typescript if I publish a package in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to Typescript and I'm trying to figure out how should I handle my props validation with React and Typescript.

Basically, I would like to use Typescript to define props but if I want to publish a package, does the user need to have Typescript to see errors with props validation ? In this case, do I need to use PropTypes also for users who don't have Typescript ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

PropTypes exist solely for plain Javascript and its missing type safety. With Typescript they are no longer necessary.

When exporting a package you can automatically create a typings file (*.d.ts) which gets published along with your transpiled code. Editors like vscode will pick it up and ensure type safety for users of your package.